# webdriver.remote.os=WINDOWS not working in serenity 3.4.3

Tags: webdriver, selenium-grid, serenity-bdd, remotewebdriver

I am trying to run serenity provided webdriver in selenium grid hosted in my organisation machine and trying to set the remote os platform as WINDOWS using webdriver.remote.os=WINDOWS in serenity.properties file but every time remote webdriver goes to Linux OS (we have both OS in host machine).

I tried doing the same through azure pipeline using -Dwebdriver.remote.os=WINDOWS but this is also not making any difference.
If I use **RemoteWebDriver** instance with capability as cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS); it works.

Also there is no Error in the logs.